# Can I rate a song in iTunes (on a Mac) using Perl?

Tags: perl, itunes

I've tried searching CPAN.  I found `Mac::iTunes`, but not a way to assign a rating to a particular track.

Comment: The Mac::itunes stuff is crap. They should let people like that upload to CPAN. I'm curious, though, what you're doing. I just moved all my stuff to a new computer, which loses all the ratings, so I'm thinking about how to get all that back.

Comment: Brian, http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20070130165510807 and http://hifiblog.com/past/2006/05/11/howto-move-your-itunes-music-while-preserving-library-data-when-you-dont-let-itunes-manage-your-music-library/ both look promising. In short, to get things back, delete it and re-copy it the prescribed way. Easier if you let iTunes manage your library.

Comment: @Rob: actually, I merged libraries from many computers, so none of that helps. If it were a simple matter of copying files I would have already solved it. :)

Comment: @Brain I'm attempting to write something that will consume the iTunes XML created on one machine & rate the matching music on another.  (Basically, so I can take the iTunes XML off my Vista desktop & bring those ratings over to what I copied to my Mac.)  

If you want the script, hit me up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write AppleScript to fully control iTunes, and there is a Perl binding `Mac::AppleScript`.

**EDIT** Code Sample:

```
use Mac::AppleScript qw(RunAppleScript);

RunAppleScript(qq(tell application "iTunes" \n set rating of current track to $r \n end tell));
```

Comment: That was the route I started down, but other parts of the task would be trivial in Perl & insanely difficult in Applescript.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not excited by Mac::AppleScript, which just takes a big blob of AppleScript text and runs it, you might prefer [Mac::AppleScript::Glue](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mac-AppleScript-Glue/), which provides a more object-oriented interface. Here's the equivalent to Iamamac's sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Mac::AppleScript::Glue;
use Data::Dumper;

my $itunes = Mac::AppleScript::Glue::Application->new('iTunes');
# might crash if iTunes isn't playing anything yet
my $track = $itunes->current_track;
# for expository purposes, let's see what we're dealing with
say Dumper \$itunes, \$track;

say $track->rating; # initially undef
$track->set(rating => 100);
say $track->rating; # should print 100
```

All that module does is build a big blob of AppleScript, run it, and then break it all apart into another AppleScript expression that it can use on your next command. You can see that in the `_ref` value of the track object when you run the above script. Because al it's doing is pasting and parsing AppleScript, this module won't be any faster than any other AppleScript-based approach, but it does allow you to intersperse other Perl commands within your script, and it keeps your code looking a little more like Perl, for what that's worth.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at [itunes-perl](http://code.google.com/p/itunes-perl/), it seems to be able to rate tracks.

Comment: That script uses `Win32::OLE`, so it won't work on Macintosh.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. That line where it says "iTunes for Windows". Dur.